# Delta-Epsilon Proof of Continuity of a Function

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, continuity

Define $f\colon \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ as $\dfrac{xy}{x^2 + y^2}$ for $(x, y) \neq (0, 0)$ and set $f(0, 0) = 0$. Determine whether $f$ is continuous.
Please keep in mind that I'm not asking if $f$ is continuous only at the point $0$, but whether the entire function is continuous.

Also, if you would prefer to simplify this question into $\dfrac{1}{x^2 + y^2}$ that would still be appreciated so thanks for any help!

Comment: Theorem:  Elementary functions are continuous on their domain.

Comment: Clearly the *only* problematic point is the origin. The function's contionuous everywhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, outside of $(0,0)$ this function is clearly continuous, given that it's the quotient of polynomials (and the denominator is never zero).
At the origin, the function is discontinuous. Consider the path $\lambda(t)=(t,t)$. Then,

$$
f(\lambda(t))=\frac{t^2}{2t^2}=\frac{1}{2}
$$

for every $t\in \mathbb{R}\setminus (0,0)$. Sending $t\to 0$ through this path, the function doesn't go to $f(0,0)$, and therefore it's not continuous.

Answer (score 0):

HInts:

Let $y=kx,  (k\not=0)$. Then $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{kx^2}{x^2+k^2x^2}=\frac{k}{1+k^2}\not= 0 $